Plotting multiple customised rasters in a raster stack with colours already selected from viridis palette in R
Method
I'm working with satellite AQUA MODIS Lm3 files for chlorophyll-a, sea surface temperatures and sea surface salinity, and I calculated depth, slope and rugosity from GEBCO files using the terra package. I've calculated the mean raster for each geophysical feature and they have been converted to a raster layer using the function raster::raster() in the raster package.
Aim
I've customised a couple of the raster layers using the colour palette from the viridis package and I want to visually represent my raster layers (3 columns x 2 rows - see the raster stack plotted below ) neatly for a poster presentation at a conference.
Issue
I don't want use the par(mfrow=c(3,2)) method as I'd like all my raster layers to be contained in one object for further plotting at a later date.
I've tried many different ways and I just can't figure this out being a novice.
Can I use the function rasterVis::biplot or the package ggplot for this?
I have placed the raster layers into a raster stack for species distribution modelling
#Stack the predictors into a raster stack object 
Predictors <- stack(resampled_sss, resampled_sst, resampled_chla, slope, depth, rugosity)
plot(Predictors)

However, I'd like to plot all of these customised raster layers with these colour selections and titles
#Plot the raster layers
plot(resampled_sss, main = "Mean Sea Surface Salinity (kg/m3)")
plot(resampled_sst, main = "Mean Sea Surface Temperature (°C)")
plot(resampled_chla, main = "Mean Chlorophyll-a (kg/m3)")
plot(depth, main = "Depth (m)")
plot(slope, col=rev(map.pal("viridis",100)), main="Slope (degrees°)")
plot(rugosity, col=rainbow(50), main="Rugosity (degrees°)")

Plot from the raster stack

I'd like the plots for 'Slope' and 'Roughness (Rugosity)' to look like this


You might use coltab() function in {terra} to assign a color table to your raster/layer:
library(terra)
#> terra 1.7.83
r <- rast(ncols=3, nrows=2, vals=1:6)
coltb <- data.frame(value=1:6, col=rainbow(6, end=.9))
coltab(r) <- coltb
terra::plot(r)



s <- rast(ncols=3, nrows=2, vals=1:6)
coltb <- data.frame(value=1:6, col = rev(map.pal("viridis",6)))
coltab(s) <- coltb
terra::plot(s)



t <- c(r, s)
terra::plot(t, main = c("Title 1", "Title2"))


In {raster} package the function is called colortable().
Created on 2024-10-23 with reprex v2.1.0
